# SQL Server 2008 Express Edition Connection Issue

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I have VS 2008 Professional Edition. After the installation (which included SQL Server 2008), I decided to install SQL Server 2008 Express Edition with Advanced Tools (so I could get SQL Server Management Studio on it). So I uninstalled the SQL Express that came with VS 2008, and installed the standalone SQL Server Express 2008 version with advanced tools.

However, When I try to logon onto SQL Server Management Studio using:

```
.\SQLEXPRESS
```

as Server name and Windows Authentication as the authentication, I get the following message:

```
 TITLE: Connect to Server
 ------------------------------

 Cannot connect to .\SQLEXPRESS.

 ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

 A network-related or instance-specific
 error occurred while establishing a
 connection to SQL Server. The server
 was not found or was not accessible.
 Verify that the instance name is
 correct and that SQL Server is
 configured to allow remote
 connections. (provider: SQL Network
 Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
 Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft
 SQL Server, Error: -1)

 For help, click:
 http//go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476

 ------------------------------ BUTTONS:

 OK
 ------------------------------
```

Any suggestions on how to get it to work? I have tried disabling Windows Firewall as well and still no luck.
I am using WIndows Vista and SQL Server 2008 Express SP1 Patch has also been applied recently.

**FIX: For those interested:**
I did not have any of the Instance Based installation installed (i.e. the Database engine). I Installed the instance based stuff and it fixed it!

Comment: Have you tried ComputerName\SQLExpress?

Comment: yes, I have tried that also. Same error.

Comment: May want to adjust the title to "Remote Connection Problem" to differentiate this issue (and the solutions listed) from the ones on the similar question about a "Local Connection Problem" for SQL Server 2008 Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look for your instance name in SQL Server Configuration Manager. It is written between brackets after SQL Server service in the services list.

the . notation is correct and it's the same as (local)

Comment: Apparently, "there are no items to show in this view" in the Sql Server Services section in the Configuration Manager.

Comment: Is a service not running perhaps? If so, how can I start it? I don't see SQL Server in the services section in Admin tools either?

Comment: t just shows "There are no items to show in this view." for SQL Server Network Configuration. ANd it has no sub items. In client protocols (in SQL native client 10 configuration section), Shared Memory, TCP/IP and Named Pipes are all enabled. ANd VIA is disabled.

Comment: The name of the service should be MSSQLSERVER

Comment: I don't see it in Windows Services or the Sql Server configuration manager. Is there a way to start it?

Comment: If you don't see it in Windows Services, then it is not installed. You sould try to re-install.

Comment: Cheers,,, I didn't isntall the instance-based stuff... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Start your Local SQL Server Service**

- **Start SQL Config Manager:**  Click Start -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 -> SQL Server
  Configuration Manager
- **Start SQL Services:**  Set the SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) and SQL Server Browser services to automatic
  start mode. Right-click each service -> Properties -> Go into the Service Tab

This will ensure they start up again if you restart your computer.  Please check to ensure the state is "Running" for both services.

[image: Starting up your Local SQL Server 2008 Service]

**Login and authenticate with your Local SQL Server**

- Now open up SQL Server Management Studio and click "Connect to Object
  Explorer" and select Server Name:

*[Your PC name]\SQLEXPRESS*

**Example:**  *8540P-KL\SQLEXPRESS or (localhost)\SQLEXPRESS*

- To find your PC name:  Right click My Computer -> Properties ->
  Computer Name tab
- **Alternative:**  Login using windows authentication:  Using the user name [Your
  Domain]/[Your User Name]

[image: SQL Server 2008 User Account Settings]

**Setup User Account**

- **Create a new Login acct:**  In SQL Mgmt Studio -> Expand your local Server -> Security -> Right
  click on Logins -> New Login
- **Set Password settings on New User Account:**  Uncheck Enforce password policy, password expiration and user must
  change pw(Since this is local) Default database -> Your Database
- **Grant roles to New User Account:**  User Mapping Page -> Map to your db and grant db_owner role Status
  Page -> Grant Permission to connect and Enable Login

[image: SQL Server 2008 User Settings Local DB]

**Setup Access Permissions/Settings for User**

- **Enable all auth modes:** Right click your Local Server -> Properties -> Security Tab -> Enable
  SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode
- **Enable TCP/IP:**  Open SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network
  Configuration -> Protocols for SQLEXPRESS -> Enable TCP/IP
- **Restart SQL Server Service:**  You will have to restart the SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) after enabling TCP/IP

[image: SQL Server 2008 Server Permissions]

**Database Properties File for Spring Project**

- database.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://[local PC Computer
  name];instance=SQLEXPRESS;DatabaseName=[db name];
- database.username=[Your user name] database.password=[Your password]
- database.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

If you want to view larger screen shots and better formatting of the answer with more details please view the blog article below:
[Setting up a Local Instance of SQL Server 2008 Blog Post:](http://www.rtssys.com/blog/archives/14.html)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using (local)\SQLEXPRESS in the name?  I've not seen that . notation before.

Comment: This fixed my issue, did not need browser service after all.

Answer (score 1):

Scott,

I had to enable SQL Server Browser in services once I did that I was able to connect on My recent install.

after that I only had to use the computer name as the server.

edit,
while researching further on finding sql server browser, noted that reporting services, service showed its instance as .\computer name.

try that as the server name.

edit again change to backslash been playing with linux recently :)

Comment: I can't find "SQL Server Browser" in Windows Services (Admin Tools).
How can I start/enable this?

Comment: you installed sql server express with advanced tools correct,  sql server browser even shows up on the standard install. so it should be in services. if not sounds like something happened with install.
not an expert on this fumbled around until I found that in services and it worked even found my sql server instance on the laptop.

Comment: I am running the installation again. Apparantly, I do not have any of the Instance Based installation installed (i.e. the Database engine). I suspect this is the problem: I will let you know when the installation is complete.

Comment: Also had this problem tonight, and it was the browser service that got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that you installed as Default instance. In this case, try connecting using (local) - just (local).
Then go to Programs/Microsoft SQL Server/Configuration Tools/SQL Server Configuration Manager. Go to SQL Server Network Configuration/Protocols for MSSQLSERVER and enable Named Pipes.

Comment: I believe it is something to do with instance. So what do I type in: Just "(local)" - I get error "Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)" if so. Any other I get Error 26 again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the SQL Server Surface Area Configuration?  You might only have SQL Authentication setup and might need to enable Network and SQL Authentication.

-JFV

Comment: is there a standalone for SQL Server Surface Area Configuration in 2008 ( i think there was in 2005, can't find it for 2008). But in Configuration Manager, I see no items in SQL Server Services and SQL Server Network Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have an application that uses a connection string trough VSOT in Word 2007.
The application gave a connection error.
I allways install Sql server 2008 Express R2 in mixed mode so that i can use the build in sa with i password to connect.
I re-entered the password to be sure its correct. In a next step i opened:
‘Configuration manager’ in ‘Program files’ ‘Microsoft Sql Server 2008’ –->’ Configuration Tools’ and set all the other instances on the properties --> hide instance 'yes'
That solved the problem in my case.
Danny

Answer (score 0):

If you still have problems connecting to SQL Express 2008,

read this article
http://www.linglom.com/2009/03/28/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/

It tells you about configuring SQL express after installation